# XPO Export to TFS not updating certain properties

Tags: tfs, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, morph-x

I am having an issue with certain properties for certain fields from updating.

For example:

I changed the "Help Text" property for String 30 to be blank, and checked that into TFS. By the time the build finished, the changes I made weren't even pulled down. This is part of the file after I made the change in my AOT.

```
STRING
PROPERTIES
  Name                #String30
  Label               #@SYS97920
  HelpText            #@SYS97921
  Origin              #{29081355-0000-1000-5374-72696E673330}
  LegacyId            #4949
  StringSize          #30
ENDPROPERTIES
```

And here is the file after I went in and exported it manually:

```
STRING
PROPERTIES
  Name                #String30
  Label               #@SYS97920
  Origin              #{29081355-0000-1000-5374-72696E673330}
  LegacyId            #4949
  StringSize          #30
ENDPROPERTIES
```

The HelpText was not showing (as I wanted it to) on my local machine, but it didn't get exported to TFS.

Here is another example. I edited the Label for Start Time, End Time, and Comments on a custom table. Here is the export before I changed those labels:

```
 FIELD #Comments
    STRING
    PROPERTIES
      Name                #Comments
      Table               #omitted
      Origin              #omitted
      StringSize          #50
    ENDPROPERTIES


  FIELD #EndTime
    TIME
    PROPERTIES
      Name                #EndTime
      Label               #End
      Table               #omitted
      Origin              #omitted
      ExtendedDataType    #TimeOfDay
    ENDPROPERTIES

  FIELD #StartTime
    TIME
    PROPERTIES
      Name                #StartTime
      Label               #Start
      Table               #omitted
      Origin              #omitted
      ExtendedDataType    #TimeOfDay
    ENDPROPERTIES
```

And here it is afterwards:

```
FIELD #Comments
    STRING
    PROPERTIES
      Name                #Comments
      Table               #omitted
      Origin              #omitted
      StringSize          #50
    ENDPROPERTIES

  FIELD #EndTime
    TIME
    PROPERTIES
      Name                #EndTime
      Label               #End Time
      Table               #omitted
      Origin              #omitted
      ExtendedDataType    #TimeOfDay
    ENDPROPERTIES

  FIELD #StartTime
    TIME
    PROPERTIES
      Name                #StartTime
      Label               #Start Time
      Table               #omitted
      Origin              #omitted
      ExtendedDataType    #TimeOfDay
    ENDPROPERTIES
```

In my local AOT, the Comments field had the "Comments" as its label. I pulled down the latest changed from TFS and it erased the label. So I checked it out, changed the label, and checked it back in. TFS told me nothing changed and just undid the check out. Actually exporting the XPO results in this:

```
      FIELD #Comments
    STRING
    PROPERTIES
      Name                #Comments
      Label               #Comments
      Table               #omitted
      Origin              #omitted
      StringSize          #50
    ENDPROPERTIES
```

So the file obviously changed, but TFS export didn't recognize it or something. Does anyone have any insight into why this is happening?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem yet?

Comment: I just ended up editing the .xpo in a text editor manually.